# Localizable Information in App Store Connect resets after release

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I really don't understand how Localizable Information works in App Store. When the new version in the draft status, we fill in the Name and Subtitle fields. Then, when this version is in the "In Review" or "Pending Release" state everything looks good and these files are in the locked state, please see the screenshot:
[image]

But after the build is released all languages are deleted except English, and we have to add them again:
[image]

That's really annoying. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you still see the localized metadata on the App Store? Are you sure you're browsing the App Store Connect page for the latest released version? Try creating a new one and see if your metadata carries over. Try different browsers and the App Store Connect app.

Comment: Hey! 1) Yes, I can see localized metadata on the App Store. 2) I think I'm browsing the correct version (I clicked on the latest version and then on App Information). I created a new version but I see incorrect localization (It looks like it pulled Eng version to all locales): https://take.ms/MtgdH

Comment: @Vym I have the same problem in Safari as well, but it looks correct in Connect iOS app!

Comment: Do you have full owner privileges for your app, or are your privileges restricted? This may be the problem. Other than that, I suggest you try cleaning you browsers' data and/or signing out and back in. If that didn't work, there's probably not much you can do other than filing a bug to Apple.

Comment: My coworker and I have this problem, we use different computers and users (he's a full owner of app). Thank you! I'll try to reach Apple support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug on App Store Connect bug and I believe they fixed it.